# Cannot set a value when an object contains Vector of another objects

Tags: c++, vector

I have implemented a c++ programm that contains the following classes:

```
class Wheels{
  private:
    bool _needToChange;

  public:
    void SetNeedToChange (const bool needToChange) {_needToChange =  needToChange;} 

};


class Car {
  private:
     vector<Wheels> _wheels;
  public:
     vector<Wheels> GetWheels() {return _wheels;}
};
```

Inside main I create a vector of cars:

```
int main(){
    vector<Car>_cars;

   //Inside two nested for loops I need to set the boolean value 

   _cars[iter1].GetWheels()[iter2].SetNeedToChange(true);
 }
```

However, the value is always false after that. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Return by reference if you want to access the vector in `Car`: `vector<Wheels>& GetWheels() {return _wheels;}`.

Comment: Why is `_wheels` private anyway? If you want to allow external code to access it, make it public (and ditch the trivial accessor anti-pattern).

Comment: In order to understand why you are not getting expected result below answer can be referred. But modifying internal data of class breaks encapsulation. Better modify the data via member_functions.

Comment: `_cars[iter1].SetWheelNeedToChange(iter2, true);` would look better at least from design point of view

Comment: @IInspectable We know too little about the class to simply degrade it into a data holder. At this point he uses it like one, sure, but what if he wants to add something like for example a variable changeRequired?

Comment: Using accessor like this: `vector<Wheels>& GetWheels() {return _wheels;}` is of use only for adding loging or maybe adding breakpoints to find when it is called. More usefull would be const read only version - `const vector<Wheels>& GetWheels() const {return _wheels;}`

Comment: @Aziuth: If, at some point, you find the need to add a `changeRequired` field, I'd argue that you are storing redundant state. Encapsulating state is a powerful tool to reduce complexity. Using it to hide the fact, that you have introduced redundant state is - however common - malpractice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several answers tell you to make the returned vector a reference. This works, sure, but this hurts your encapsulation. One could easily do something like GetWheels().resize(0);, which should not be possible from the outside.

Therefore, go with an accessor:

```
 Wheels& GetWheels(const unsigned int position){return _wheels[position];}
```

and call it with

```
 _cars[iter1].GetWheels(iter2).SetNeedToChange(true);
```

This assumes that it is okay to access a Wheels object from the outside. You might instead opt to encapsule it even further, with something like

```
void setWheelNeedToChangeStatus(const unsigned int position, const bool status){
    _wheels[position].SetNeedToChange(status);
}
```

By the way, not sure what kind of naming standard you use, but usually, methods are in lower case, at least in any convention I know.

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
 vector<Wheels> GetWheels() {return _wheels;}
```

you return a **copy** of the wheels vector. If you change it, the changes are not applied to the member vector, only to the copy.

Return a reference instead:

```
 vector<Wheels>& GetWheels() {return _wheels;}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are returning by copy:

```
 vector<Wheels> GetWheels() {return _wheels;}
```

so you modify a copy which is destroyed after the end of this line. What you want is to return a reference:

```
 vector<Wheels>& GetWheels() {return _wheels;}
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~!!
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting a copy of the _wheels vector.

If you want to be able to change the values, better return it as a reference like this:

```
vector<Wheels>& GetWheels() {return _wheels;}
```